# How do I lock out the front fork on my RST Neon shock?

Tags: shocks

I have a Trek 7150SE(Scheels Edition) that came stock with a RST Neon front fork. I would like to lock it for road biking but haven't been able to figure out how.

I tried to turn the top of each side of the fork but it wouldn't budge by hand. I then tried a basic plumbing wrench and if started to strip the plastic.

Is it possible to lock this fork, and if so, how?

[image: left fork]

[image: right fork]

[image]

Comment: The Neon comes with or without the lockout, If it has one its on the right hand side. Guessing yours does not have it

Comment: @mattnz added a picture of the top of the right fork. Does that clear any doubt if I have a lockout or not? I take it not? I don't even know what it looks like to have it...

Comment: Would have a lever on it. - http://rstsuspension.com/en/forks/city-trekking/neon

Comment: @mattnz Can you add your comments as an answer so I can upvote and choose as the best answer? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RST Neon comes both with a lockout and without a lockout.  If your unit has a lockout, it can be found on the right hand side.  By looking at the image of the top right fork it appears that you do not have the model with the lockout.

You can see an example of what the lockout looks like here: http://rstsuspension.com/en/forks/city-trekking/neon